# ASP.NET Aspx View - How to Remove Unused Variable Warnings

Tags: asp.net, view

My company has a zero warning tolerance policy and I have a warning that I just can't get to go away. It is showing on the **declaration of the string** because

```
Warning 1   The variable 'message' is assigned but its value is never used
```

This is the code snippet:

```
<% 
    string message = "Message to be displayed";
    if (Model.Count == 0)
    {
        %>
        No records to display. <%= message %>
        <%
    }
    else
    {
%>
```

The rest of the code is correct, so it's not a syntax error.

Why would this kind of warning appear in the first place when I am clearly referencing it?

Thx in advance!

Comment: even css class warnings in partial views?

Comment: I would not trust VS warnings coming from the WebForms view engine, or really any designer for that matter. Perhaps a better approach would be to have a policy about unit testing rather than warnings. Code that compiles can still be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declare as below, this issue will be fixed.

When you see this kind of warning, just review the declare. It will OK then.

```
<% 
if (Model.Count == 0)
{
    string message = "Message to be displayed";  // declare message here :)
    %>
    No records to display. <%= message %>
    <%
}
else
{
%>
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thx for focusing on the question.

Answer (score 4):

It's strange that your company has 0 tolerance to errors and still lets you write C# code in your views which turn them into spaghetti. Also you are hardcoding urls instead of using URL helpers which is very bad.

So you could start by slightly improving the code:

```
<% if (Model.Count == 0) { %>
    No records to display. 
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Click here to add.", "Details", "ObjectDefinition") %>
<% else { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: Ha! They wouldn't like it if they had seen it ;) It's a new project that I'm working on so really nobody has seen it yet. Going to revise the code to avoid that ghastly error. Thx for the reminder about the URL helper. However, I'm still wondering about the reason for the warning and how to fix it...

Comment: Sure does, and thx for that. I fixed my code on this end so nobody will notice it :P, but I'm wondering about the more general case though. Why would that warning appear when the string is clearly being used?

Comment: You should also look at T4MVC to avoid using magic string : http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC